# Can't hide Intel XDK splash screen

Tags: android, splash-screen, intel-xdk

I have created a small game and created build using Intel XDK. I installed it in device and can see the splash screen. I tried what is mentioned in other topics but unable to remove the splash screen.

```js
function onDeviceReady(){
    if( navigator.splashscreen && navigator.splashscreen.hide ) {
         navigator.splashscreen.hide();
 }
 if( window.intel && intel.xdk && intel.xdk.device ) {
  if( intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen ) {
   intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
  }
        intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation("landscape");
        intel.xdk.device.setAutoRotate(false);
        intel.xdk.device.hideStatusBar();
 }
}
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

This is how it looks initially when I launch the app.

[image]

I have this plugin added in the project
cordova-plugin-splashscreen

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received this answer on XDK forum

> The purpose of the splashscreen is to hide the details of the
>   initialization process (even before your device ready fires). The
>   splashscreen you see is the default cordova splash screen, you can
>   replace it by your own graphics. You can upload custom splashscreen
>   through Launch Icons and Splash screens on Projects page. The
>   hidesplashscreen() method will hide the splashscreen that is displayed
>   at the initialization and the contents of your app will appear (which
>   happens when device is ready).